# UFW rules for VPN

Tags: vpn, ufw

I have set up a VPN box on my lan.

My lan gateway is 192.168.2.1.

I set port forwarding on my router to allow incoming VNP connections.
The VPN box LAN address is 192.168.2.42

The tun0 interface that OpenVPN creates is 10.8.0.0/24

It all works just fine. Clinets are assigned fixed i/p addresses etc.

**But** I want to restrict some (but not all) of my VPN clients from being able freely to access other machines on my LAN and accessing each other.

My plan is that there is only **one** machine on my LAN they should be allowed to have access to - but only to the NodeRed and MQTT ports (1880 / 1883). My desired VPN firewall blocks all other possibilities.

Let's say that this permitted LAN machine is 192.168.2.200

The VPN clients I wish to restrict in this way all all given i/p addresses 'upwards' from 10.8.0.20 - I can easily change these to whatever if that helps the UFW ruleset...

The VPN client that IS allowed to access my LAN entirely is 10.8.0.11 This 'favoured client' should also be able to access all the other VPN clients without restriction.

**Please can someone tell me the UFW ruleset that will achieve this?**

I have tried many many options but apart from locking myself out a couple of times (!), I cannot prevent any machine in the VPN range from 'connecting back' through the VPN gateway to other machines on my LAN.

My suspicion is that I do not understand some NAT issue or other properly :(

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

If you edit /etc/openvpn/server.conf , you can modify the push directives to control which routes are pushed to the client.
You could probably remove the currently enabled statements and just use this:

`push "route 192.168.2.200 255.255.255.255"`

Along with that, you might need to disable this:

`push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"`

Also, if you read the comments in server.conf, there may be some other options you want to tweak.

For the port specific blocking, I would do that at the server firewall.

Comment: Hi Aaron Are you saying that I would not be able to achieve what I need using ONLY UFW rules? For me, with a live VPN, it is much less of a liability to change UFW rules than get involved in a per-client tweak of the VPN server conf.... If at all possible I just want to use UFW... ?